# Can we do better than zero padding of FFT?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, probability-theory, soft-question

My background is in signal processing and never took any course related to functional analysis or even advanced algebra. But I have a strong conviction (may be wrong) that we may be do better then zero padding as given below:

Consider we have a $N$ complex time domain samples (with unknown noise)  and we want to estimate the spectral density. Spectral density is nothing but square of the Fourier Transform of the signal. Let $N$ be the length of the original signal $x_n=x_0, x_1 \cdots x_{N-1}$ and let $X(\omega)$ be its DTFT , $X(\omega)= \sum x_n \exp(-i \omega n)$. It is easily seen that the number of DTFT bins in this case is also $N$. In our problem we want to have a better resolution in frequency axis. In other words we want to get more DTFT bins than $N$. A common approach here is to zero pad $x_n$ as much as you want and then perform Fourier Transform as before to get more frequency bins.

I think by zero padding we are doing some sort of interpolation (trigonometric?). Can we do something better (else)? Something better means retain the original roughness if the roughness is correct? Equivalently, can't we built some sort of topological structure from $x_n$; Assuming that $x_n$ has come from a structure and then do the interpolation? I do not know what else can we do so the examples of "something else" may not be relevant. I am looking for answers related to the limitation/restriction applicable of this problem. A perfect answer may be explain why we cannot do anything other than zero padding?

Comment: I don't know anything at all about the FFT, but my father has a problem with some code he's working on pertaining to the FFT for signal processing. Could I connect you to him, if you have a moment to help him out? I'm not asking for any commitment, just that he's been struggling with his problem for a while, and I've been learning as much as I can to help him, but FFT is really outside my knowledge (I'm an undergrad algebra student). If you feel like you have a moment, I can be reached at my school email alfred.yerger@stonybrook.edu. I'll pass on his contact information.

Comment: Why don't you ask at [dsp.se] instead? Or rather, search for existing discussions such as [Advantages/disadvantage of zero padding](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/22034).

Comment: @3дравый Смысл  I was expecting an answer in terms of limitation/bound of Bochner's theorem or something else and assumed it is more related to math then dsp.